# How can pass an object of a class to another class's method?

Tags: java

How can I pass an object of a class to another class's method without interface or inheritance?

I need to pass an object of a class called `Project` to a method of class `Developer`. Can Java help me to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look on this sample code,

```
public class Project {

  public Project() {

   Developer developer = new Developer();
   developer.developerMethod(this);
  }
}

public class Developer {

public void developerMethod(Project project) {
 // do something
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass references to any reference type, no matter if it's a class, an interface, an array type, an enum, an annotation or if it's `abstract`, `final` or even `strictfp`:

```
public class Project {
}

public class Developer {
  public void myMethod(Project foo) {
    // do something with foo
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the class `Developer` contains a method that takes an argument of type `Project` or any type that `Project` inherits from, including `Object`, then you can pass an object of type `Project` to a method within `Developer`

Answer (score 0):

If you can choose the type of your method's parameter, it's quite simple:

```
class Project {
}

class Developer {
    public void complete(Project p) {
    }
}

class SoftwareHouse {
    public void perform() {
        Developer d = new Developer();
        Project p = new Project();
        d.complete(p);
    }
}
```

If the type of the argument is fixed and it isn't an interface or a super-class of `Project` you need to write an adapter class:

```
interface Assignment {
}

class Developer2 {
    public develop(Assignment a) {
    }
}

class ProjectAssignment implements Assignment {
    private Project p;

    public ProjectAssignment(Project p) {
        this.p = p;
    }
}

class SoftwareHouse2 {
    public void perform() {
        Developer2 d2 = new Developer2();
        Project p2 = new Project();
        Assignment a = new ProjectAssignment(p);
        d2.develop(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks all for the answers. i just passed 7 days with java...and just from a few moments ago with stackoverflow.com... joachims answer is all i need for now.. as i go further these remaining answers will mean a lot for me i hope.. thank u all